# Is VM Instance required to be setup to host Static Files? - Newb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, static-files

I am completely new to Gcloud and trying to learn setting up bit by bit.

I changed my nameservers to Gcloud
Tried to create a A record and Cname. For A record I generated a Static IP. But it is asking me to attach the IP to an Instance.

I created a bucketlist for my domain -- Say example.com and uploaded an index.html file. But the site is not working when i type example.com/index.html

Am I missing something.

Thanks a lot for the helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to serve up pages directly from Google Cloud Storage without using a VM, but using a custom domain name. You can do this, but the method does not involve creating an A record or a static IP address. It does involve creating a CNAME, but it is a special CNAME pointing at "c.storage.googleapis.com.", and then naming your bucket to match your domain name.

For the exact details see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website.